# Why is SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex still giving downtime?

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I've defined my 'Products_index' to use the SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex type to rebuild itself. I see that the index generates 2 folders: 'Products_index' and 'Products_index_sec'. However when I'm rebuilding the index manually (sitecore control panel) and meanwhile trying to get results from the index it is not giving results back when rebuilding the **secondary** index.

So scenario:

1. Rebuild index manually
2. meanwhile index is giving results back.
3. Rebuild index complete.
4. everything fine.
5. Rebuild index manually (again) (so now it's rebuilding the secondary folder)
6. meanwhile index is **not** giving results back.
7. Rebuild index complete.
8. everything fine again.

Index config looks like this:

```
<index id="Products_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    ...
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
      <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <Database>master</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore</Root>
      </crawler>
    </locations>
</index>
```

I'm getting results with the following code (through a web api call)

```
using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(MediqBusiness.Constants.Search.ProductIndex).CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<ProductSearchResultItem>().Where(searchItem => searchItem.Name != "__Standard Values"
                && searchItem.TemplateName == "Product" && searchItem.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);

    //additional query fields here..

    var results = query.GetResults();
    return results;
}
```

Sitecore version: Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 141226)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We had the following issue when we were using the Sitecore SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex. We contacted Sitecore and they provided with a patch which is the **#457624**.

What the SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex normally does is when you are rebuilding your Sitecore Indexes, it will switch between the directory. Supposed at the moment, the main directory is **Products_index** and you launch a rebuild index. What happen is that you will now hit the **Products_index_sec**. When rebuilding the index a second time, the directory will switch again to **Products_index**.

What we have observed is that you will need to rebuild the indexes twice. We already log a ticket to the Sitecore Support portal from which they provide us the **patch #457624**

Thanks

Comment: So did you experience downtime during one of the index rebuilds like us? And has the patch #457624 fixed that for you?
Could you please elaborate on what the patch actually fixes?

Comment: We experience the issue whereby the secondary index were not being rebuild properly and we were having lot of errors in the log. Since we applied the patch we have not encountered any issues with the SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex

Comment: Is the patch available for download somewhere? And is there a description/documentation available from Sitecore explaining what the patch actually fixes?

Comment: You will need to contact Sitecore Support for the patch and I don't think there is currently a documentation about it.